# Can't resize extended partition

Tags: 12.10, partitioning

I'm trying to use GParted from the Ubuntu live CD and it won't allow me to resize the main extended partition. There is a "key" symbol next to it and the "unmount" option is grayed out.

Comment: it looks like the picture below, only the "key" symbol is only by the sda5 partition inside of the extended partition. That is the partition I am unable to unmount or change.

Answer (score 0):

There probably is a *secondary* partition in that extended partition (like /dev/sda5 within /dev/sda2 in the picture)

[image]

**EDIT:** you did forget to follow my first sentence :-)

**First** you have to make sure that that partition is **not mounted** and then you must ensure that it leaves enough space inside the extended partition to make it smaller (if you want that).

Comment: I am trying to make it smaller and it looks exactly like the picture(except the only "key" symbol on mine is the one by the sda5 partition), but the real problem is i cannot resize the partition inside of the extended partition.

Comment: In that case unmount the "inner" partition - then you should be able to resize it.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a swap partition inside of the partition that you want to resize, you'll have to "swapoff" the swap partition first. You should be able to resize the other partition afterwards.